# Azure Open AI for Images not generating images

Tags: azure-openai

I have a node.js function which calls the API for generating images. My text completions work just fine. HOwever when i am sending the prompt for generating images it is returning that there are no results found.

here is my code

```html
async function generateImage(paragraph) {
  const endpoint = process.env.API_AI_IMAGE_ENDPOINT;
  const azureApiKey = process.env.API_AI_IMAGE_KEY;

  const prompt = paragraph;
  const size = '256x256';
  const n = 1;  // Change to 1 for only one image

  async function main() {
    console.log('== Batch Image Generation ==');

    const client = new OpenAIClient(endpoint, new AzureKeyCredential(azureApiKey));
    const response = await client.getImages(prompt, { n, size });

    if (response && response.images && response.images.length > 0) {
      const image = response.images[0];
      console.log(`Image generation result URL: ${image.url}`);
    } else {
      console.log('No images found in the results or job not yet completed.');
    }
  }

  main().catch((err) => {
    console.error('The sample encountered an error:', err);
  });
}

generateImage("a monkey eating a banana");
```

The results are Job Details: {
id: '35ccf911-cac7-4a1e-bc65-16418c7ade66',
created: undefined,
expires: undefined,
result: undefined,
status: 'notRunning',
error: undefined
}

for some reeason its not generating any result.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing this behavior is because you are not using the SDK correctly. If you read the documentation for [`getImages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/openai/openaiclient?view=azure-node-preview#@azure-openai-openaiclient-getimages) method, you will notice that it returns a promise of [`ImageGenerations`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40azure/openai/imagegenerations?view=azure-node-preview) which does not have `images` property. Instead it has a `data` property which is either an array of [`ImageLocation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40azure/openai/imagelocation?view=azure-node-preview) or [`ImagePayload`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40azure/openai/imagepayload?view=azure-node-preview).

So assuming you get an array of object of type `ImageLocation`, your code would be something like:

```
const response = await client.getImages(prompt, { n, size });
if (response && response.data && response.data.length > 0) {
    const image = response.data[0];
    console.log(`Image generation result URL: ${image.url}`);
} else {
    console.log('No images found in the results or job not yet completed.');
}
```

Comment: I am getting No images found in the results or job not yet completed. -> console.log on response prints the following {
  id: 'f6e67d4a-f3a1-4fc1-9eb7-e7cf390c0059',
  created: undefined,
  expires: undefined,
  result: undefined,
  status: 'notRunning',
  error: undefined
}

Comment: Have you made the changes in your code I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: yes I did, after that I got that msg. I ghink something is wrong in end point structure maybe. I'm using https://xxxxx.openai.azure.com

Comment: is it because I have a completion model also deployed?

Comment: Let me try by running the code.

Comment: any success on it?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I’m getting weird “DeploymentNotFound” error when running the code.